# jQuery/UI - .html update on drag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I'm currently absolutely positioning 180 "hot spots"

It's not fun.  I figured I could save myself a bit of time and display the top and left numbers on drag so it's easier for me to input.

I'm able to drag and get the position by inspecting the element.  But I thought I may be able to eliminate the middle man and just .html what I need into the element.

**Here's a fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/q0huu15t/1/

```
$(function() {
    $( ".drag" ).draggable();
});

$(function() {
    var $this = $( ".drag" );
    var top = $this.css("top");
    var left = $this.css("left");

    $this.html('Top: ' + top +'<br /><br />Left: ' + left);

});
```

I'd like for the numbers to update "live" when I drag.  Is this possible?  I've tried a few ways and this is the closes I've gotten.

`var top = $this.attr("style", "top");`

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

So I sort of figured it out myself.

Probably not the best way to do it but it works and it's not staying so who cares.

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(function() {
        var $this = $( ".drag" );
        var top = $this.css("top");
        var left = $this.css("left");

        $this.html('Top: ' + top +'<br /><br />Left: ' + left);

    });
}, 1);
```

Basically running the function over and over.  It only works for the first one and this `var $this = $( ".drag" ).each();` doesn't work!  This is good enough for me though.  So hopefully it helps somebody else out there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing that setInterval with 1ms delay isn't a very good practise as you have so many iterations which are just overhead.

As described in the documentation (see [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#events)) jQuery Draggable provides several events you can use.

I wrote a snippet for u to get used to working with events (as you obviously dont know about the usage of them):

```
$(function() {    
  $(".drag").draggable();    

  $(".drag").on('dragstop, dragstart, drag', function(){
    // update "live"
    $this=$(this);
    $this.html('Top: ' + $this.css("top") +'<br /><br />Left: ' + $this.css("left"));
  }).each(function(){
    // initial write cause the "dragcreate" event obvsly doesnt work
    $this=$(this);
    $this.html('Top: ' + $this.css("top") +'<br /><br />Left: ' + $this.css("left"));
  });
});
```

I also created a working fiddle for u [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q0huu15t/5/)

I hope that helps you ;)

Comment: Thank you!!  Much better than what I had :)